# Threading Distribute[]

Tags: expression-manipulation

I wish to use `Distribute[p.(q+r)+m]` to get `p.q+p.r+m`. However, Distribute apparently does not thread through all parts of the expression. What should I do instead?

Comment: Is `Distribute[#] & /@ (p.(q + r) + m)` acceptable ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks This is not good because if there is a function like `Log[a+b]` inside the expression, the distribute would expand that too, yielding `Log[a]+Log[b]`.

Comment: @QuantumDot That would be a different question, too.

Comment: Oh, that's true.  On second thought, never mind.

Answer (score 5):

You could also define special symbols that distribute *themselves* when they get combined with `Plus` under a `Dot` operation. Here I denote those symbols with a hat:

```
Clear[OverHat];
OverHat /: Dot[x___OverHat, Plus[y__OverHat], z___OverHat] := 
 Plus @@ Thread[Dot[x, {y}, z]]
```

Then you can enter your expression like this:

```
OverHat[m] + OverHat[p].(OverHat[q] + OverHat[r])
```

where the `OverHat` is more easily input using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`7`+`^` to get this:

[image: overhat]

Answer (score 4):

You don't give a lot of context about how the target expression is generated (interactively or via code). The documentation for `Distribute` indicates that it won't automatically map down through an expression. But, one way to do this comes to mind.

Via code, using `ReplaceAll` and a replacement rule:

```
expr=p.(q+r)+m
expr /. d : HoldPattern[Dot[_, Plus[_, _]]] :> Distribute[d]
(* m + p.q + p.r *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  p.(q + r) + m /. Dot -> Composition[Distribute, Dot]
  (* m + p.q + p.r *)

  Log[p.(q + Log[r + s])] + Log[a + b] + m /.  Dot -> Composition[Distribute, Dot]
  (* m + Log[a + b] + Log[p.q + p.Log[r + s]] *)
```